# Where is JB launcher repository and why Trebuchet's src folder in CM10 is empty?

Tags: android, launcher, cyanogenmod

There is no Launcher2 repository in github.com/android, and directory Trebuchet/src in CM10 is empty. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trebuchet needs to be re-written to work on JellyBean.  I'm sure their working on it,  though it might take a while